# Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: java.io.File.getSampleV

Tags: java, filter, noise

```
import java.io.File;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

//import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class filterpanitha {
//public void graph(){

//}
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // First, get the data from a sound file in .wav format into your program
    // You will have to modify the following line to point to your own file
    // String fileName = "C:\\Huhns\\Teaching\\CSCE145\\Code\\Noise3\\preamble.wav";
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\sudharshan_03713\\Desktop\\audio\\1A5.wav");
    // Next, print the sound to find out its length in samples
    System.out.println(file);
    // The following two methods calls get the value of a sound sample at
    // index 1000 and then set its value to half of the original.
    int index = 1000;
    int value = file.getSampleValueAt(index);
    file.setSampleValueAt(index, value / 2);
    // The following loop sets every sound sample to be twice its original value
    for (int n = 0; n < file.getNumSamples(); n++) {
        value = file.getSampleValueAt(n);
        file.setSampleValueAt(n, value * 2);
    }

    // Listen to the sound
    //sound1.play();
}
}
```

please help when i run its says

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: java.io.File.getSampleValueAt
 at Prepro.filterpanitha.main(filterpanitha.java:41)
```

i have no idea why its pooping up ...is ther any audio format i need to look in to if so how ...please help

Comment: Which line is line 41?

Answer (score 5):

This exception `java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code` is seen when using an IDE which allows you to run your project/code, even if some classes are not compiled (due to errors in code). I suggest fixing your code and you have zero errors before running your project.

Also, `java.io.File` never have the method `setSampleValueAt()`. This is what causes your code to never compile.

Answer (score 2):

Your error is in this line

```
int value = file.getSampleValueAt(index);
```

[`File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) doesn't provide the method `getSampleValueAt`.