# method not recognised in java

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have an issue with a program i want to code. I would like to enter a date , and find the Excel numeric representation using POI libraries. I would like later to search in a Excel table for this specific date.
Here my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DateUtil;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFDateUtil;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;

public class readExcel { 

static double exDate; 
public static void main( String [] args ) {

    try{

        Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);

       /*Enter the date and capture it*/
        String Date_Choice;
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.print("Enter your date choice (yyyy/mm/dd): ");
        Date_Choice = user_input.next();
        System.out.println("You chose the following date: " + Date_Choice);


        Date d =  sdf.parse(Date_Choice);
        exDate = getExcelDate(d);
        System.out.println(exDate);
    } 
    catch (ParseException ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace(); 
     }

       /*convert the datae into an integer*/
        HSSFDateUtil.parseYYYYMMDDDate(Date_Choice);

   }
}
```

I have those issues: the compile does not the getExcelDate method . Also at the last line of code , the Date_Choice variable which is a string ing not recognised. when i run the code , I have the following compiling error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code -       erroneous sym type: getExcelDate
 at readExcel.main(readExcel.java:44)
    Java Result: 1 

Line 44 is : exDate = getExcelDate(d);
```

I believe to have the proper libraries.. Please can I have some advice?

Comment: Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16767950/uncompilable-source-code-erroneous-sym-type-java-io-file-getsamplev

Comment: Where is `getExcelDate()` defined ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the following:

```
  import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFDateUtil;
```

and then you can use

```
  exDate = HSSFDateUtil.getExcelDate(d);
```

Try the above and let me know its working for you or not.

Comment: Thank you Sankumarsingh . It works well. i need to familiarize more with the OOP concepts. i will continue my program and let you guys know if any problem. Thank you!