# PrintScreen in java only working when main?

Tags: java, screenshot, javax.imageio

I've been trying to add this code to my project :

```
public static void Save() throws HeadlessException, AWTException, IOException
{
    Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    Dimension Dim = tk.getScreenSize();
    Rectangle screenRect = new Rectangle(Dim);
    Robot r = new Robot();
    BufferedImage screenCapturedImage = r.createScreenCapture(screenRect);
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MM dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = new Date();
    String FileName = dateFormat.format(date);
    ImageIO.write(screenCapturedImage, "png", new File("/home/caio/Desktop/"+FileName+".png"));
}
```

it gives me this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: RoboCore.Print.Save
    at Core.Start.main(Start.java:23)
Java Result: 1
```

I want to call this method to print the results on my screen, but this code won't work because it's not a main method, it seems very strange to me...

Comment: Are you getting any errors when you attempt to call the method from anywhere other than main?

Comment: how are you calling this method is not working?

Comment: what do you mean by "wont work"?

Comment: `throws Exception`: not good. Please replace with specific exceptions.

Comment: it gives me an error unless its a main method : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: RoboCore.Print.Save
 at Core.Start.main(Start.java:23)
Java Result: 1

Comment: @Bathsheba which Exception should I use?

Comment: @CaioPetrelli `throws Exception` is not relevant to your immediate problem - it doesn't actually break anything, but it might make it harder to understand your program later. About your error: "uncompilable source code" means you have compile errors and your IDE lets you run programs with compile errors. How are you calling Save?

Comment: @immibis im calling like : Save();

Comment: possible duplicate of [this] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16767950/uncompilable-source-code-erroneous-sym-type-java-io-file-getsamplev)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried compiling and running your code, I don't get any issues when calling it from `main`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   try {
      Save();
   } catch (Exception e) {
      // Handle the exception
   }
}
```

Comment: I've called from main just for a test but the method its actually called later on with user input from a UDP Server

Comment: @CaioPetrelli interesting, please share more/relevant code where it is being called.

Comment: Does it save the image? because it seams like the try catch clause stoped the error but does not save the image

Comment: @CaioPetrelli yes it does take screenshot correctly. I'm not sure of the greater context in which you are calling `Save()` so it makes it hard for us to help further without updating your Q.

Comment: so it gets a server UDP packet and returns that to a class witch checks if the server recived the string "TakeScreenShot" than calls the method

Comment: it worked now god knows why... but it was missing some catch{} bits

Comment: @CaioPetrelli glad it's working for you now. `catch` is necessary as `Save()` may throw various exceptions which you need to handle.

Answer (score 1):

public static void main(String args[])

{

```
 //remaining code write here;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void save() throws AWTException, IOException
{
        Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    Dimension Dim = tk.getScreenSize();
    Rectangle screenRect = new Rectangle(Dim);
    Robot r = new Robot();
    BufferedImage screenCapturedImage = r.createScreenCapture(screenRect);
    Format dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH_mm_ss");
    Date date = new Date();
    String FileName = dateFormat.format(date);

    ImageIO.write(screenCapturedImage, "png", new File("/home/caio/Desktop/" + FileName + ".png"));
    }
```

try that code it worked for me.

your problem was in the ImageIO.write method, you added " where unneeded

all i changed was "/home/caio/Desktop/"+FileName+".png" to "/home/caio/Desktop/" + FileName + ".png"

and the date format

then call it by

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   try
   {
       save();
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
       System.out.println(e);
   }
}
```

Comment: That just ignores the fact that he wanted the file name to be based on the date...

Comment: Sorry I over looked that change the date to a yyyy.mm.dd hh.mm.ss format and then change the  ImageIo.write to "directory + fileName + .png"

Comment: I have fixed all problems and all should work well now. good luck